# SpringWS service doesn't response for any requests via SOAP UI

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-ws

SpringWS service doesn't response for requests via SOAP UI?

Collegues, i am beginner in Spring and i need help. I created web service and can receive wsdl description in SOAP UI, but the problem is that service does not respond for requests. 
This my web srvice config:

```
package com.mayacomp.app;

import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.EnableWs;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.XsdSchema;

@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/services/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "APPService")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema APPServiceSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("ApplicationWS");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/APPService/");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://mayaapp.com/application");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(APPServiceSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }



    @Bean
    public XsdSchema APPServiceSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("META-INF/schemas/application.xsd"));
    }

}
```

My endpoint class:

```
package com.mayacomp.endpoint;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.ResponsePayload;

import com.mayacomp.app.InternalHistRequest;
import com.mayacomp.app.InternalHistResponse;
import com.mayacomp.app.InternalCreditHistFlagsType;
import com.mayacomp.app.InternalCreditHistIndicatorsType;
import com.mayacomp.app.ResponseHeaderType;
import com.mayacomp.service.APPService;



@Endpoint
public class WsEndpoint {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(WsEndpoint.class.getName());

    private static final String TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://mayaapp.com/application";



    @Autowired 
    public APPService APPService_i;


    @PayloadRoot(localPart = "InternalHistRequest", namespace = TARGET_NAMESPACE)

    public @ResponsePayload InternalHistResponse getInternalCredHist(@RequestPayload InternalHistRequest request) {
           LOG.info("Test");



           InternalHistResponse _return = new InternalHistResponse();


          _return.setClientID(new java.math.BigInteger("42823928316076042522945935239155481381"));   


          try
          {

          ResponseHeaderType _returnResponseHeader =  new ResponseHeaderType();
          _returnResponseHeader.setRequestUid("RequestUid-207722529");
          _returnResponseHeader.setRequestTimestamp(javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2015-05-06T10:28:37.616+03:00"));
          _returnResponseHeader.setResponseUid("ResponseUid2066314058");
          _returnResponseHeader.setResponseTimestamp(javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2015-05-06T10:28:37.616+03:00"));
          _returnResponseHeader.setResponseCode(1883325675);
          _returnResponseHeader.setResponseDescription("ResponseDescription-1084371447");
          _return.setResponseHeader(_returnResponseHeader); 

          /* call Spring injected service implementation to retrieve credit history data */
           InternalCreditHistFlagsType _returnInternalCreditHistFlags =  APPService_i.getInternalCreditHistFlagsType(request);
           _return.setInternalCreditHistFlags(_returnInternalCreditHistFlags);
           /* call Spring injected service implementation to retrieve credit history data */
           InternalCreditHistIndicatorsType _returnInternalCreditHisIndicators = APPService_i.getInternalCredHist(request);
           _return.setInternalCreditHisIndicators(_returnInternalCreditHisIndicators);

            return _return;

          }

       catch (java.lang.Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }



    }

    public void setAPPService(APPService APPService_p)
    {
        this.APPService_i = APPService_p;
    }




}
```

My pom file (may be something with dependencies)

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.mayacomp.pco
    APPService

```
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>APPService Spring-WS Application</name>
<url>http://www.springframework.org/spring-ws</url>

<inceptionYear>2015</inceptionYear>
<packaging>jar</packaging>




<build>
        <finalName>PCOService</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                    <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/META-INF/schemas</schemaDirectory>
                    <includeSchema>**/*.xsd</includeSchema>
                       <bindingDirectory>src/main/java/com/mayacomp/app</bindingDirectory>
                    <enableIntrospection>false</enableIntrospection>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>



        </plugins>
    </build>
  <dependencies>




    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
              <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
              </exclusions>
    </dependency>


      <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>



     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
         <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

As i said i have available wsdl after

> mvn -U spring-boot:run

via url
http://localhost:8080/services/APPService/APPService.wsdl but operations are not working. Please, help.

**UPDATE** 
Spring boot log trace:

```
DEBUG: [авг-03 13:08:33,082] boot.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application started with classpath: [file:/C:/Users/Maya/workspace/APPService/src/main/resources/, file:/C:/Users/Maya/workspace/APPService/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.0.0/classmate-1.0.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.14/snakeyaml-1.14.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.12/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jms/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-jms-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/springframework/ws/spring-ws-support/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-ws-support-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.4.0/jackson-annotations-2.4.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.12/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.12/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/springframework/ws/spring-xml/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-xml-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.0.9.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.4.6/jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-log4j-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/wsdl4j/wsdl4j/1.6.3/wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.1.3.Final/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/springframework/ws/spring-ws-core/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-ws-core-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.0.9.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.23/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.23.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.23/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.23.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.23/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.23.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-messaging/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-messaging-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-oxm/4.0.9.RELEASE/spring-oxm-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-ws/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-ws-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.12/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.4.6/jackson-core-2.4.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.23/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar]
DEBUG: [авг-03 13:08:33,572] springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Loading source class com.mayacomp.app.WsApplication
DEBUG: [авг-03 13:08:33,627] context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener - Skipped config file 'file:./config/application.xml' resource not found
DEBUG: [авг-03 13:08:33,627] context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener - Skipped config file 'file:./config/application.yml' resource not found
DEBUG: [авг-03 13:08:33,628] context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener - Skipped config file 'file:./config/application.properties' resource not found
DEBUG: [авг-03 13:08:33,628] context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener - Skipped config file 'file:./config/application.yaml' resource not found
DEBUG: [авг-03 13:08:33,629] context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener - Skipped config file 'file:./application.xml' resource not found
DEBUG: [авг-03 13:08:33,629] context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener - Skipped config file 'file:./application.yml' resource not found
DEBUG: [авг-03 13:08:33,630] context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener - Skipped config file 'file:./application.properties' resource not found
DEBUG: [авг-03 13:08:33,630] context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener - Skipped config file 'file:./application.yaml' resource not found
DEBUG: [авг-03 13:08:33,631] context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener - Skipped config file 'classpath:/config/application.xml' resource not found
DEBUG: [авг-03 13:08:33,631] context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener - Skipped config file 'classpath:/config/application.yml' resource not found
DEBUG: [авг-03 13:08:33,632] context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener - Skipped config file 'classpath:/config/application.properties' resource not found
DEBUG: [авг-03 13:08:33,632] context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener - Skipped config file 'classpath:/config/application.yaml' resource not found
DEBUG: [авг-03 13:08:33,633] context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener - Skipped config file 'classpath:/application.xml' resource not found
DEBUG: [авг-03 13:08:33,633] context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener - Skipped config file 'classpath:/application.yml' resource not found
DEBUG: [авг-03 13:08:33,634] context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener - Skipped config file 'classpath:/application.properties' resource not found
DEBUG: [авг-03 13:08:33,634] context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener - Skipped config file 'classpath:/application.yaml' resource not found
INFO : [авг-03 13:08:33,642] context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@731b45a8: startup date [Mon Aug 03 13:08:33 MSK 2015]; root of context hierarchy
DEBUG: [aug-03 13:08:33,649] context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Bean factory for org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@731b45a8: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5ff5d9af: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,wsApplication]; root of factory hierarchy
DEBUG: [aug-03 13:08:35,233] context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@2fffdd6a]
DEBUG: [aug-03 13:08:35,233] context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Using ApplicationEventMulticaster [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@4cc2be65]
DEBUG: [aug-03 13:08:35,658] embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory - Code archive: C:\Users\Maya\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.2.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
DEBUG: [aug-03 13:08:35,659] embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory - Code archive: C:\Users\Maya\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.2.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
DEBUG: [aug-03 13:08:35,660] embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory - Document root: C:\Users\Maya\workspace\APPService\src\main\webapp
INFO : [aug-03 13:08:35,705] embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
DEBUG: [aug-03 13:08:36,156] context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans - Added existing Servlet initializer bean 'dispatcherServlet'; order=2147483647, resource=class path resource [com/mayacomp/app/WebServiceConfig.class]
DEBUG: [aug-03 13:08:36,271] context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans - Created Filter initializer for bean 'characterEncodingFilter'; order=-2147483648, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration.class]
DEBUG: [aug-03 13:08:36,272] context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans - Created Filter initializer for bean 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter'; order=-2147483638, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]
DEBUG: [aug-03 13:08:36,827] context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans - Created EventListener initializer for bean 'requestContextListener'; order=2147483647, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]
INFO : [aug-03 13:08:36,830] context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean - Mapping servlet: 'messageDispatcherServlet' to [/services/*]
INFO : [aug-03 13:08:36,837] context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
INFO : [aug-03 13:08:36,838] context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
DEBUG: [aug-03 13:08:36,987] context.web.OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter - Initializing filter 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter'
DEBUG: [aug-03 13:08:36,989] context.web.OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter - Filter 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' configured successfully
DEBUG: [aug-03 13:08:36,990] context.web.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter - Initializing filter 'characterEncodingFilter'
DEBUG: [aug-03 13:08:36,990] context.web.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter - Filter 'characterEncodingFilter' configured successfully
DEBUG: [aug-03 13:08:37,676] context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@5579e98a]
DEBUG: [aug-03 13:08:37,682] autoconfigure.logging.AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer - 


=========================
AUTO-CONFIGURATION REPORT
=========================


Positive matches:
-----------------
bla bla
Negative matches:

bla bla

INFO : [aug-03 13:08:37,877] embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
```

Comment: Your error/trace log is helpful, could you post?

Comment: @s.kwiotek, sorry. I added it. But it is only spring boot log. Hope it helps.

Comment: I dont see Plugin configuration for maven to build Java classes from the XSD file.

Comment: s.kwiotek, do you mean this <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>?

Comment: Yes. Try to solve with new Maven build.

Comment: s.kwiotek, thank you for not leaving me. look into pom (build section). I added plugin which generated enities which are used in endpoint class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84998/discussion-between-s-kwiotek-and-may12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please delete double entries in your pom:

- spring-boot-starter-log4j
- spring-boot-starter-ws

In your WebServiceConfig please add:

```
servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
```

You have to generate domain classes based on an XML schema automatically during build time. So please add this to your POM and modify schemaDir and outputDir for your requirements:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.6</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>xjc</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>xjc</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</schemaDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
</configuration>
```

I see that your main application is in package com.mayacomp.app and you have annotated this class with @SpringBootApplication. So it is important to have your WS Components located under the package com.mayacomp.app, otherwise the component scan cant find them. Be aware to have your targetNamespace identical in depending Components and in your SoapEnvelop Element of Xml-Request. 
You can give it a try on your Endpoint /services and with an test file like test.xml for example with curl:

```
curl --header "content-type: text/xml" -d @test.xml http://localhost:8080/services/
```

Comment: s.kwiotek, thank you once again. One more question: i want to add one more operation (e.g. getWeather) into WebSiervice. I add method getWeather to WsEndpoint.java and i have a proplem: service responses me {"timestamp":1443709281706,"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported","path":"/AppService/"}. Can you help?

Comment: Please could you post your WSDL File. I would have a look.

Comment: s.kwiotek, i have decided problem. Thank you one again for your example )

Comment: "So it is important to have your WS Components located under the package com.mayacomp.app, otherwise the component scan cant find them" thanks sven.kwiotek